# Trying to prove $A = \{1, 4, 10\}$ is compact without using the Heine Borel Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Here's my attempt:

Proof:

Let $A = \{1, 4, 10\}$ and let $A_n = (-n,n), n \in \Bbb N$.

Take $\mathscr F = \{A_n:n\in \Bbb N\}$. For $n \gt 10, \mathscr F$ is an open cover for set $A$.

Let $\mathscr G \subseteq \mathscr F$ where $\mathscr G = \{A_n:10 \lt n \le 12\}$ for $n \in \Bbb N$.

Since $\mathscr F$ is an open cover for $A$ and has a finite subcover $\mathscr G$, $A$ must be compact.

---

Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A compact space is a space where **every** open cover has a finite subcover. You have just shown the property for one open cover.

Try to think of all the possible open coverings that could exist for $\{1,4,10\}$.

Comment: Ah I see, I'll see what I can do. Thank you.

Comment: So instead of saying: "Take $\mathscr F = \{A_n:n\in \Bbb N\}$. For $n \gt 10, \mathscr F$ is an open cover for set $A$", would I just say "take $\mathscr F = \{A_n:n\in \Bbb N\}$. Since $A$ is contained in the union of the open sets in $\mathscr F$, $\mathscr F$ is an open cover for $A$." And then I can take the same $\mathscr G$?

Comment: If all this is in $\mathbb{R}$,  $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (1-\frac{1}{n}, 1+\frac{1}{n}) \cup (4-\frac{1}{n}, 4+\frac{1}{n}) \cup (10-\frac{1}{n}, 10+\frac{1}{n})$ is an open cover that is not of the form $A_n$ and not an element of your $\mathscr{F}$. For proving the theorem, I would use the fact that all closed subsets of a compact set are compact, and we know $[a,b]$ is compact, although there might be a more elementary way.

Answer (score 3):

You are overcomplicating this.

Let $A$ be a finite set. Let $\mathcal C$ be an open cover of $A.$ Each $a \in A$ must lie in some $C_a \in \mathcal{C},$ so that $\bigcup_{a\in A}C_a$ is a finite subcover for $A$.